# Problem building CNN only using python numpy when gradient descent and batching

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I am currently learning the book Grokking Deep Learning by Andrew W. Trask. But I have problems understanding the code in Chapter 10 of the book, on building a CNN only using python and numpy:

```py
import numpy as np, sys
np.random.seed(1)
from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
images, labels = (x_train[0:1000].reshape(1000, 28*28)/255, y_train[0:1000])
one_hot_labels = np.zeros((len(labels), 10))
for i, l in enumerate(labels):
    one_hot_labels[i][l] = 1
labels = one_hot_labels
test_images = x_test.reshape(len(x_test), 28*28)/255
test_labels = np.zeros((len(y_test), 10))
for i, l in enumerate(y_test):
    test_labels[i][l] = 1
def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)
def tanh2deriv(output):
    return 1-(output**2)
def softmax(x):
    temp = np.exp(x)
    return temp/np.sum(temp, axis=1, keepdims=True)
alpha, iterations = (2, 300)
pixels_per_image, num_labels = (784, 10)
batch_size = 128
input_rows = 28
input_cols = 28
kernel_rows = 3
kernel_cols = 3
num_kernels = 16
hidden_size = ((input_rows-kernel_rows)*(input_cols-kernel_cols))*num_kernels
kernels = 0.02*np.random.random((kernel_rows*kernel_cols,num_kernels))-0.01 
weights_1_2 = 0.2*np.random.random((hidden_size, num_labels))-0.1 
def get_image_section(layer, row_from, row_to, col_from, col_to): 
    section = layer[:,row_from:row_to, col_from:col_to]
    return section.reshape(-1, 1, row_to-row_from, col_to-col_from)
for j in range(iterations):
    correct_cnt = 0
    for i in range(int(len(images)/batch_size)):
        batch_start, batch_end = ((i*batch_size), ((i+1)*batch_size))
        layer_0 = images[batch_start:batch_end]
        layer_0 = layer_0.reshape(layer_0.shape[0], 28, 28)
        sects = list()
        for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
            for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):
                sect = get_image_section(layer_0, row_start, row_start+kernel_rows, col_start, col_start+kernel_cols)
                sects.append(sect) 
        expanded_input = np.concatenate(sects, axis=1) 
        es = expanded_input.shape 
        flattened_input = expanded_input.reshape(es[0]*es[1],-1) 
        kernel_output = flattened_input.dot(kernels) 
        layer_1 = tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0], -1)) 
        dropout_mask = np.random.randint(2, size=layer_1.shape)
        layer_1 *= dropout_mask*2
        layer_2 = softmax(np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2)) 
        for k in range(batch_size):
            labelset = labels[batch_start+k:batch_start+k+1]
            _inc = int(np.argmax(layer_2[k:k+1])==np.argmax(labelset))
            correct_cnt+=_inc
        layer_2_delta = (labels[batch_start:batch_end]-layer_2) / (batch_size*layer_2.shape[0])
        layer_1_delta = layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T)*tanh2deriv(layer_1)
        layer_1_delta*=dropout_mask
        weights_1_2 += alpha*layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
        l1d_reshape = layer_1_delta.reshape(kernel_output.shape)
        k_update = flattened_input.T.dot(l1d_reshape)
        kernels -= alpha*k_update 
    print("I:"+str(j), "Train-Acc:", correct_cnt/float(len(images)))
```

I know the code formatting is quite dense and a bit hard to read. But it is working properly, with a test accuracy of about 87.5% as anticipated. However, I want to know more about why the code is working, and have a few questions about some places of the code:

First, on the batching part.

```py
layer_2_delta = (labels[batch_start:batch_end]-layer_2) / (batch_size*layer_2.shape[0])
```

I already know that because the batch size is 128, you process 128 images at a time, and the `(labels[batch_start:batch_end]-layer_2)` delta is actually the total delta of all 128 images. So normally the "delta" should be divided by 128 to get the average delta of that layer. However this time the code divides that delta again by `layer_2.shape[0]`, which is also the same as the batch size 128. I don't understand why I should do this. If I remove the extra 128, the code will fail to run. The program will end up with numpy warning "overflow" on the exp function(softmax) and then the training accuracy just stays at 8.7%. Why is this extra "/128" essencial to the code?

Another problem with the gradient descent. I learned that earlier in the book, gradient descent is like this:

```py
delta = target_output - real_output
weight += input*delta*alpha
```

But here I'm facing the code with

```py
kernels -= alpha*k_update
```

I used to think there is a problem with the code. But after "correcting" the "-" to a "+", I got a similar result on the AI model, with a test accuracy of 86%. How is this possible? There must be something fundemental about gradient descent that I haven't fully understood. What's the difference between the minus and the plus sign in gradient descent, and how to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is just a constant that is removed. It effectively corresponds to a "learning rate". If you remove it, you get [this phenomenon](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/nn-learning-rate/) where your learning rate is too high:

[image]

---

(2) If you change *all* weight updates from:

```
for weight in weights:
    weight -= learning_rate * dloss_dweight
```

to:

```
    weight += learning_rate * dloss_dweight
```

...then it is no longer finding the minimum loss. It is now finding the maximum of the loss, i.e., the worst possible model.

However, in your case, you only changed it for one layer's weights, so what probably happens is that your other parameters compensate for it.

Comment: Thanks! So you mean there can exist another constant similar to the "learning rate" when batching? But I still have another question about (2). According to your answer, updating the weights should all be "-"s. So you mean the code is actually wrong? Can I correct it by making the "-" to a "+"?

Comment: The code is pretty messy, but it looks like the `_deltas` are the negative of the derivatives. The `_update` is the positive derivative. Confusing code, but it all (probably) correctly follows the first formula that I wrote.

Comment: the `_update` variable doesn't seem like the positive derivative to me.  I still think it should be `kernels += alpha*k_update ` instead of a '-='.

Comment: I posted [an issue](https://github.com/iamtrask/Grokking-Deep-Learning/issues/65) on github corresponding to the repository of the book. I am increasingly starting to think that the original code itself has a typo.